# apache .htaccess redirect regex

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need this redirect 301 rule in apache .htaccess:

```
/catalog/{category_slug}/{product_slug}
```

to

```
/product/{product_slug}
```

example:

```
/catalog/cat1/prod1 to /product/prod1
/catalog/cat1/prod2 to /product/prod2
/catalog/cat2/prod3 to /product/prod3
```

and also:

```
/en/catalog/abc/xyz to /en/product/xyz
/es/catalog/abc/xyz to /es/product/xyz
...
...
```

Could you please help me?

tks
Simone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On # no need to do this twice, once is enough

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+\/)?catalog\/[^\/]*\/([^0-9].*) /$1product/$2 [R=302,QSA,L]
```

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.

This will redirect:

1. **/catalog/abc/xyz** to **/product/xyz**
2. **/catalog/abc/123/xyz** to **/product/123/xyz**
3. Also redirect with the query string because of `QSA` flag.

Comment: I need it to work with too:

/en/catalog/abc/xyz to /en/product/xyz

/es/catalog/abc/xyz to /es/product/xyz
...
...

tks

Comment: @SimoneGrimani ok, let me add that

Comment: @SimoneGrimani try it now

Comment: it does not work
now the first option without language is also broken

Comment: @SimoneGrimani it works for me. Are you changing it in anyway

Comment: @SimoneGrimani try it now

Comment: i don't understand. It prepend me also the absolute path: "https://www.my-site/var/www/mysite/public/product/product1"

Comment: @SimoneGrimani oh!, are you inserting it in httpd.conf/apache2.conf? This shouldn't happen with .htaccess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241360/discussion-between-simone-grimani-and-example-person).

Comment: I found a problem I hadn't considered.

If it is a numeric value, the redirect must not be done because it is pagination. Example:
 
/catalog/cat1/prod1 => ok redirect.
 
/catalog/cat1/2 => no redirect, it is category pagination. 
Do you think it can be fixed?

Comment: @SimoneGrimani try it now

Comment: Now it is OK. Thanks again you are really very good.

Comment: @SimoneGrimani You can accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^catalog/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ /product/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the "{product-slug}" (3rd path segment) from the capturing group in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*.